# How can I signal a forked child to terminate in Perl?

Tags: perl, multithreading, fork

How can I make the same variable shared between the forked process? Or do I need to write to a file in the parent then read the value saved to the file in the child once the file exists? $something never appears to get set in this so it just loops in the sleep

```
my $something = -1;
&doit();
sub doit
{

 my $pid = fork();
 if ($pid == 0)
 {
      while ($something == -1)
      {
         print "sleep 1\n";
         sleep 1;
      }
      &function2();
 }
 else
 {
     print "parent start\n";
    sleep 2;
    $something = 1;
    print "parent end: $something\n";
 }
}

sub function2 {
   print "END\n";
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`perldoc -f fork`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#fork):

> File descriptors (and sometimes locks on those descriptors) are shared, while everything else is copied.

See also [Bidirectional Communication with Yourself](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlipc#Bidirectional-Communication-with-Yourself) in `perldoc perlipc`.

**Update:** On second thought, do you want something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $pid = fork;

die "Cannot fork: $!" unless defined $pid;

if ($pid == 0) {
    print "Child start\n";
    my $end;
    local $SIG{HUP} = sub { $end = 1 };

    until ($end) {
        print "Sleep 1\n";
        sleep 1;
    }
    function2();
}
else {
    print "Parent start\n";
    sleep 5;
    kill HUP => $pid;
    waitpid($pid, 0);
}

sub function2 {
    print "END\n";
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> w
Parent start
Child start
Sleep 1
Sleep 1
Sleep 1
Sleep 1
Sleep 1
END
```

Answer (score 6):

Variables aren't normally shared between processes, if you want to communicate 2 processes you better use pipes or shared memory or any other IPC.

Comment: Don't link to pirated copies of books.

Comment: Didn't notice, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to share state among multiple processes using an interface that superficially looks like read/write access to variables, you may want to have a look at [`IPC::Shareable`](http://search.cpan.org/~bsugars/IPC-Shareable-0.60/lib/IPC/Shareable.pm).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use threads; processes are not threads (although at one point in time Linux threads were implemented using a special type of process which shared memory with its parent).

Comment: Note that by default all variables in perl threads are thread-local - see perldoc threads::shared for more information

Comment: I very much doubt that.  The use cases for perl threads are few and far between.

Comment: @ysth And sharing data between parallel tasks is one of them.

Comment: @Schwern: yes, is more convenient with threads, but it's a leap to go from there to "you want to use threads".

Comment: @ysth: Eh, what I meant was, "given what you say you want to do, this is probably a good way to go". Not necessarily saying that people should use threads willy-nilly, or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.  [Threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html), [sockets](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Sockets:-Client/Server-Communication), [IPC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#SysV-IPC) and writing to a file with file locking.  Personally I'd recommend threads, they're very easy and safe in Perl, most installations have them compiled and they're fairly performant once a thread has been created.

An interesting alternative is the [forks](http://search.cpan.org/dist/forks) module which emulates threads using a combination of fork() and sockets.  I've never used it myself but Elizabeth Mattijsen knows her threads.