# How to execute subroutine in parallel?

Tags: perl

I want to know how to execute two subroutines in parallel.

In Perl Tk, I am using  one buttons widget and text widget.

Button : is to execute the parser function 
Text   : is to display the print statement of the parser

Thing is that after executing the parser function only the text widget is getting executed 
[because Perl support sequential execution]

But I want both of them to be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a [fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) and have the child process launch the second subroutine and communicate the results to the parent process via [interprocess communication (IPC)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html).

You can also try to use [threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html), though it would not be my recommended solution

P.S. The discussion on this SO question should also prove informative, though is not 100% the duplicate of your need:

[How can I signal a forked child to terminate in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260639/how-can-i-signal-a-forked-child-to-terminate-in-perl)

Comment: What’s your experience with `IPC::Shareable`?

Comment: @tchrist - Aware it exists, never used. I like the POD warning: "Certainly; this is beta software..."